# Deserialize JSON object that has the same object as member in it

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I am having trouble with de-serializing a json which has the structure like following.

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id;
    public string EntityName;
    private List<Entity> _items;

    //Sub entities
    public IReadOnlyList<Entity> Items
    {
        get{
               return _items;
           }
    }
}
```

While in debug mode, 
I could able to see the Items > 0 via JSON Visualizer(as in below image) but when I try to de-serialize I always get the Items count = 0

[image]

I tried using following statements, but still no luck.

```
var json = await response.GetContentAsync<string>();
```

Try 1

```
var deserializedList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerabld<Entity>>json);
```

Try 2

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings{MaxDepth = 5};
var deserializedList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IReadOnlyList<Entity>>(json, settings);
```

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have this `IReadOnlyList` which makes it impossible for the serializer to add something to it.

Answer (score 1):

The first option will be to make is `IList<Entity>` but if want to keep it as `IReadOnlyList<Entity>` you can do that by supplying a setter for it -

```
    public IReadOnlyList<Entity> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        set
        {
            _items = _items ?? new List<Entity>();
            if (value == null)
                return;
            _items.AddRange(value);
        }
    }
```

Here is an example -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because your public property is `IReadOnlyList` deserializer is unable to set a value there. To solve this you need to apply `[JsonProperty]` attribute to `_items` field

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id;
    public string EntityName;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Items")]
    private List<Entity> _items;

    //Sub entities
    [JsonIgnore]
    public IReadOnlyList<Entity> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it? Does it work? I see this error - `A member with the name 'Items' already exists on 'TestConsole.Entity'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name.`

Comment: Add [JsonIgnore] to another field.